# Why does the calculation of Cohen's kappa fail across different packages on this contingency table?

Tags: r, package

I have a contingency table for which I would like to calculate Cohens's kappa - the level of agreement. I have tried using three different packages, which all seem to fail to some degree. The package `e1071` has a function specifically for a contingency table, but that too seems to fail. Below is reproducable code. You will need to install packages `concord`, `e1071`, and `irr`.

```
# Recreate my contingency table, output with dput
conf.mat<-structure(c(810531L, 289024L, 164757L, 114316L), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(landsat_2000_bin = c("0", "1"
), MOD12_2000_binForest = c("0", "1")), .Names = c("landsat_2000_bin", 
"MOD12_2000_binForest")), class = "table")

library(concord)
cohen.kappa(conf.mat)
library(e1071)
classAgreement(conf.mat, match.names=TRUE)
library(irr)
kappa2(conf.mat)
```

The output I get from running this is:

```
> cohen.kappa(conf.mat)
Kappa test for nominally classified data
4 categories - 2 methods
kappa (Cohen) = 0 , Z = NaN , p = NaN 
kappa (Siegel) = -0.333333 , Z = -0.816497 , p = 0.792892 
kappa (2*PA-1) = -1 

> classAgreement(conf.mat, match.names=TRUE)
    $diag
[1] 0.6708459
    $kappa
[1] NA
    $rand
[1] 0.5583764
    $crand
[1] 0.0594124
    Warning message:
In ni[lev] * nj[lev] : NAs produced by integer overflow

> kappa2(conf.mat) 
 Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)
Subjects = 2 
Raters = 2 
Kappa = 0 
z = NaN 
p-value = NaN
```

Could anyone advise on why these might fail? I have a large dataset, but as this table is simple I didn't think that could cause such problems.

Comment: Maybe, there's too few values in your data

Comment: Contingency tables usually only have 2 rows and 2 columns. I don't see any reference to minimum size - only actual size, which my table seems to fit.

Comment: Sorry. That was just an hypothesis. I have just worked once with this kind of functions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first function, `cohen.kappa`, you need to specify that you are using count data and not just a `n*m` matrix of `n` subjects and `m` raters.

```
# cohen.kappa(conf.mat,'count')
cohen.kappa(conf.mat,'count')
```

The second function is much more tricky. For some reason, your `matrix` is full of `integer` and not `numeric`. `integer` can't store really big numbers. So, when you multiply two of your big numbers together, it fails. For example:

```
i=975288 
j=1099555
class(i)
# [1] "numeric"
i*j
# 1.072383e+12
as.integer(i)*as.integer(j)
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In as.integer(i) * as.integer(j) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

So you need to convert your matrix to have integers.

```
# classAgreement(conf.mat)
classAgreement(matrix(as.numeric(conf.mat),nrow=2))
```

Finally take a look at the documentation for `?kappa2`. It requires an `n*m` matrix as explained above. It just won't work with your (efficient) data structure.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense (the integer overflow). I suspected something like that might have happened. Using 'count' for the first function, 'cohen.kappa' doesn't give _Cohen's_ kappa - just Siegel and kappa (2*PA-1). The 'classAgreement' function works perfectly with the 'numeric' modification, and agrees with the method below. Thanks!

Comment: I was actually wrong about `cohen.kappa`. It requires for `n` tests and `m` raters, it requires an `m*n` matrix, regardless of the `type`. So, in your data, you just can't use it because you have so many tests.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to know specifically why those fail? Here is a function that computes the statistic -- in a hurry, so I might clean it up later [(kappa wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa):

```
kap <- function(x) {
  a <- (x[1,1] + x[2,2]) / sum(x)
  e <- (sum(x[1,]) / sum(x)) * (sum(x[,1]) / sum(x)) + (1 - (sum(x[1,]) / sum(x))) * (1 - (sum(x[,1]) / sum(x)))
  (a-e)/(1-e)
}
```

Tests/output:

```
> (x = matrix(c(20,5,10,15), nrow=2, byrow=T))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   20    5
[2,]   10   15
> kap(x)
[1] 0.4
> (x = matrix(c(45,15,25,15), nrow=2, byrow=T))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   45   15
[2,]   25   15
> kap(x)
[1] 0.1304348
> (x = matrix(c(25,35,5,35), nrow=2, byrow=T))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   25   35
[2,]    5   35
> kap(x)
[1] 0.2592593
> kap(conf.mat)
[1] 0.1258621
```

Comment: Great, thanks - this gives the same result as the 'classAgreement' function above - reassuring!